# DBContext simplest way to update foreign key

Tags: entity-framework

```
            var orgAcc = db_.Accounts.Find(account.Id);

            db_.Entry(orgAcc).CurrentValues.SetValues(account);

            orgAcc.Company = db_.Companys.Find(account.Company.Id);


            db_.SaveChanges();
```

Is this the simplest way to update an entity's association ?

```
        public class ChartofAccount: MasterData
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(6)]
            public string Code { get; set; }

            public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string AccountName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(3)]
            public string AccountCurrency { get; set; }

            public virtual AccountCatagory Category1 { get; set; }

            public virtual AccountCatagory Category2 { get; set; }

            public string Reference { get; set; }

            public bool HasTransaction { get; set; }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way `SetValues` works is to do a property-by-property compare, and for each property from the left-hand object that is also in the argument, that has a matching type, it will update the left-hand object with the value from the argument.

I presume `account.Company` is a different type of object to `orgAcc.Company`, such as something that has come in from an MVC controller argument (ie account and it's referenced objects are not EF entities). In this case your approach seems a sound way of doing it.

That being said, `orgAcc` probably has a `Company` property, and a `CompanyId` property, in order to support the EF relationships, so, if your `account` object followed the same pattern, ie storing a `CompanyId` field directly, rather than having to navigate through the company, then SetValues could automatically update the CompanyId field, which should update the foreign key when you save changes. This way you could also avoid the step that specifically assigns the `orgAcc.Company` field.